# Git OpenSSL Filter & Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, openssl

Git newbie here.

I set up a Git repository using `openssl` filters:

```
$ cat .gitattributes 
* filter=openssl diff=openssl
```

(Entire tutorial: https://gist.github.com/873637)

Everything works like it should, except one thing. In Xcode's Version Editor, the previous version (one on the right side of the window) is presented in its encrypted form. In Terminal though, `git log` works without any issues. Any ideas how to fix Xcode's Version Editor behavior?